# import many to many relationship in CRM 2011

Tags: import, many-to-many, dynamics-crm-2011, entity-relationship, dynamics-crm-4

I am currently migrate some legacy data from CRM 4.0 to CRM2011, however, there is big barrier on the Many-to-Many relationship importing, I have search for the solution and get this from codeplex http://crm2011manytomany.codeplex.com/discussions/433816, 
when I importing data, it keep get  'Issues on line 1 - line has 1 instead of 2' error, 
any advise on it
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I don't know how that tool is working but I found [this blog](http://thecrm2011blog.blogspot.se/2011/06/how-to-import-many-to-many.html) that covers how to do an import of many-to-many. Other than that it's cusom coding that will solve this issue I'm afraid. Write a program that does what you want, it will take some time and it's not a trivial task but it might be the only way.

Answer (score 0):

The Codeplex you mention actually works, I just tested it.

There is however an issue regarding the file encoding format. As a workaround you can copy past your csv content within notepad++, use encoding UTF8 and save it -> the import will work fine then.